# Replacing a vector in a basis for a subspace of $R^N$ (numerically)

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have some basis ${u_1, u_2, .., u_k}$ for a subspace $ U \subset R^N$ (where $k$ and $N$ are typically very large). I have another vector $v \in U$. How do I (efficiently) find an $i \in {1,2,..,k}$ such that $u_1, .. u_{i-1}, v, u_{i+1}, .. u_k$ is still a basis?

I realise that I can decompose $v$ in terms of the basis, and then any $u_{i}$ that contributes to the decomposition can be replaced with $v$, but this decomposition is quite expensive, so I'm hoping another solution exists.